# Brunch groundskeeper JS minify failed on undefined: Unexpected token: punc (,) (line: 17, col: 19, pos: 664)

Tags: javascript, build, brunch

I'm using Brunch, and groundskeeper-brunch, but when I run:

```
brunch build -P
```

I get this errror:

> JS minify failed on undefined: Unexpected token: punc (,) (line: 17, col: 19, pos: 664)

But the thing is, I checked the minified file and the code belongs to Brunch itself? Am I missing something?

:(

This is the first part of the compressed file that is being generated. The error message doesn't really make a lot of sense because it looks fine to me?

```
(function(/*! Brunch !*/) {
    'use strict';

   var globals = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : global;
   if (typeof globals.require === 'function') return;

   var modules = {};
   var cache = {};

   var has = function(object, name) {
       return ({}).hasOwnProperty.call(object, name);
   };

   var expand = function(root, name) {
       var results = [], parts, part;
       if (/^\.\.?(\/|$)/.test(name)) {
           parts = [root, name].join('/').split('/');
       } else {
           parts = name.split('/');
       }
       for (var i = 0, length = parts.length; i < length; i++) {
           part = parts[i];
       if (part === '..') {
           results.pop();
       } else if (part !== '.' && part !== '') {
           results.push(part);
       }
   }
   return results.join('/');
  };
...
```

Comment: Can you show us the unminified code and the position is breaks on?

Comment: I've just been looking further into the code. Strict mode has not been used and there are a lot of inconsistencies. I would presume that the error message given might not be in the file I'm looking at. I think I need to go through, add strict mode, find any issues and fix them?